# Cannot get OneToOne Mapping working with Composite Key. Quarkus + Reactive Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, quarkus

We are migrating our application from Spring Data + Hibernate (it was working) to Quarkus Panache (version v2.16.2) + Reactive Hibernate.

```
abstract class BaseEntity<ID> : PanacheEntityBase {

    open val id: ID? = null

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(other)) return false
        other as BaseEntity<*>
        return id != null && id == other.id
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return javaClass.hashCode()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${javaClass.simpleName}<$id>"
    }
}
```

```
@Embeddable
class AssociatedAccountCompositeId(

    @Column(name = "customer_account_id")
    val customerAccountId: String,

    @Column(name = "promotion_code_id")
    val promotionCodeId: Long

) : Serializable {

    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID: Long = 845208461728L
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as AssociatedAccountCompositeId

        if (customerAccountId != other.customerAccountId) return false
        if (promotionCodeId != other.promotionCodeId) return false
        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return Objects.hash(customerAccountId, promotionCodeId)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${javaClass.simpleName}<$customerAccountId><$promotionCodeId>"
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "promotion_code")
class PromotionCodeEntity(

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "promotionCode")
    var associatedAccount: AssociatedAccountEntity?

) : BaseEntity<Long>() {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "promotion_code_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "promotion_code_sq", sequenceName = "promotion_code_sq", allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "promotion_code_sq")
    override val id: Long? = null
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_assoc")
class AssociatedAccountEntity(

    @EmbeddedId
    override val id: AssociatedAccountCompositeId,

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_code_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    val promotionCode: PromotionCodeEntity

) : BaseEntity<AssociatedAccountCompositeId?>()
```

We were migrating the project and different CompositeKey works but here I cannot make it work for few days, and the main difference in OneToOne relationship. Right now I have prepared simplest possible usecase, am getting error:

```
fun method(customerId: String, dto: PromotionCodeAssignRequestParameters): Uni<List<PromotionCodeEntity>> {
        return PromotionCodeEntity.findAll().list()
}
```

```
"Error accessing field [private java.lang.String sth.promotion_campaigns_service.enitites.id.AssociatedAccountCompositeId.customerAccountId] by reflection for persistent property [sth.promotion_campaigns_service.enitites.id.AssociatedAccountCompositeId#customerAccountId] : 1",
```

I tried obvious things like manual open instead of gradle plugin or changing val to var everywhere. 
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
I am attaching project w example https://github.com/damiankaplon/stack-question

Comment: Could you create a runnable test case somewhere?

Comment: @DavideD'Alto Hello. Thx for help! I am sharing demo project https://github.com/damiankaplon/stack-question. We have generated clean Quarkus 2.16.2. Tried to provide minimal application to invoke an error. To test locally GET localhost:8080/demo